# How would I go about getting the package names of the applications that can be Home on android

Tags: android

My activity gets set as the default Home by the user, but I want to be able to launch the default Home from within my activity as well.  I've tried hard coding the following:

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
>   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
>   PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
>   String packageName = "com.android.launcher";
>   String className = "com.android.launcher.Launcher";
>   final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, >className);
>   intent.setComponent(cn);

This seems to work on my droid, but force closes on the HTC Ally.  I'm thinking there's an easier way to just get a list of the apps that have the category Home and Default.

For those that have used the Home Swittcher app.  I essentially want to generate that list of installed default Home activities on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Create an `Intent` that launches whatever the user has for the default HOME application. In other words, do not try putting in the `ComponentName`.

Step #2: Call `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager` to find out who all can respond to that `Intent`.

Step #3: If there are only two entries in the list, find out which is yours, and the other one is the platform's. If there are 3+ entries in the list, remove yours and let the user choose among the remaining options.

You could sorta combine #2 and #3 by using `queryIntentActivityOptions()` if you like, setting it up to filter your own Intent out of the list.